# Mysql calculate multiple SUM() varialbe

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, query-performance, calculated-columns

I want to calculate 2 sum() i have tried query as below it works but very slowly. Any ideas to make it better?

```
SELECT customer, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN book_day BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'  
                THEN pax+free 
                ELSE 0 
                END) AS January,
       SUM(CASE WHEN book_day BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-31'  
                THEN pax+free 
                ELSE 0 
                END) AS February,
       ( SUM(CASE WHEN book_day BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'  
                  THEN pax+free 
                  ELSE 0 
                  END) + 
         SUM(CASE WHEN book_day BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-31'  
                  THEN pax+free 
                  ELSE 0 
                  END) ) AS total
 FROM rezervations
```

How can i make simplier like `January + February as total`

Comment: `'2020-02-31'` matches an invalid date. Btw, does `book_day` column have index on it ..?

Comment: It just looks if day exist, no metter what i send to tham. Just focus on query :)

Comment: well, then just use `SUM(CASE WHEN book_day BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-02-29'  THEN pax+free ELSE 0 END AS total`, but don't fprget to check the index out against performance issue.

Comment: @AliGüzel below query which will run faster given that there is an index on `book_day`

Comment: I wonder whether the column `book_day`s format is `DATE`, or not `DATE` ...

Comment: it's in date format, i am just looking for better way, using less sum as possible. Actualy full code is searching for whole year. I just put shorted version :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep `BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-02-29'` in where clause.

make sure there is index on book_day column

```
SELECT customer, 
SUM(CASE WHEN book_day BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31' THEN pax+free ELSE 0 END) as January,
SUM(CASE WHEN book_day BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-29'  THEN pax+free ELSE 0 END) as February,
(SUM(CASE WHEN book_day BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-02-29'  THEN pax+free ELSE 0 END) ) as total
 FROM rezervations 
WHERE
book_day BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-02-29'
```